# Electron application crash

Tags: electron, electron-builder

My electron application crashed my MAX OS also and after the crash, my machine also reboots... I attached crash logs but unable to identify the problem.. need help to identify the problem...

its cross-platform application running in Windows and mac os
The issue happens on Mac-OS only not facing issue in Windows-OS

```
 Panic(CPU 6, time 91030942173395): NMIPI for spinlock acquisition timeout, spinlock: 0xffffff86dd946290, spinlock owner: 0xffffff86d4035120, current_thread: 0xffffff86d4035120, spinlock_owner_cpu: 0x6
    RAX: 0xffffff86d42e6e30, RBX: 0xffffff937c8f50f8, RCX: 0x000000000000007e, RDX: 0x0000c6d700000000
    RSP: 0xffffffb0c94fbaa0, RBP: 0xffffffb0c94fbae0, RSI: 0xffffff86d4035120, RDI: 0xffffff937c8f50f8
    R8: 0xffffffb0c94fbc60, R9: 0xffffff801810f110, R10: 0x0000000000ffffff, R11: 0x0000000000000000
    R12: 0xffffff86d4035120, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x0000c6d83a44d73e, R15: 0xffffff86d42e6e30
    RFL: 0x0000000000000086, RIP: 0xffffff80180ccb7a, CS: 0x0000000000000008, SS: 0x0000000000000010
    Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
    0xffffffa0861f4f80 : 0xffffff80181ed5bb
    0xffffffa0861f4fd0 : 0xffffff801805fbdd
    0xffffffb0c94fbae0 : 0xffffff80180ccd04
    0xffffffb0c94fbb10 : 0xffffff801810d930
    0xffffffb0c94fbb30 : 0xffffff801810f149
    0xffffffb0c94fbbe0 : 0xffffff801810f646
    0xffffffb0c94fbc50 : 0xffffff801810e694
    0xffffffb0c94fbd10 : 0xffffff80181125e8
    0xffffffb0c94fbd50 : 0xffffff8018623364
    0xffffffb0c94fbd70 : 0xffffff801862344e
    0xffffffb0c94fbdb0 : 0xffffff801867bfdd
    0xffffffb0c94fbe30 : 0xffffff80186774e5
    0xffffffb0c94fbee0 : 0xffffff8018677311
    0xffffffb0c94fbf40 : 0xffffff80187698cb
    0xffffffb0c94fbfa0 : 0xffffff80180601f6
    
    Process name corresponding to current thread: Messenger Helper (Rendere
    Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev
    
    Mac OS version:
    20D74
    
    Kernel version:
    Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:07:06 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
    Kernel UUID: C86236B2-4976-3542-80CA-74A6B8B4BA03
    KernelCache slide: 0x0000000017e00000
    KernelCache base: 0xffffff8018000000
    Kernel slide: 0x0000000017e10000
    Kernel text base: 0xffffff8018010000
    __HIB text base: 0xffffff8017f00000
    System model name: MacBookPro15,2 (Mac-827FB448E656EC26)
    System shutdown begun: NO
    Hibernation exit count: 0
    
    System uptime in nanoseconds: 91030942201103
    Last Sleep: absolute base_tsc base_nano
      Uptime : 0x000052cacaf93731
      Sleep : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
      Wake : 0x0000000000000000 0x000000247201b306 0x0000000000000000
    last started kext at 79553737469483: >usb.!UUserHCI 1 (addr 0xffffff7fb899e000, size 102400)
    last stopped kext at 79620393454569: >usb.!UUserHCI 1 (addr 0xffffff7fb899e000, size 102400)
    loaded kexts:
    com.Cylance.CyProtectDrvOSX 1
    @filesystems.smbfs 3.4.1
    >!APlatformEnabler 2.7.0d0
    >AGPM 119
    >X86PlatformShim 1.0.0
    @fileutil 20.036.15
    @filesystems.autofs 3.0
    >!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver 4030.5
    >!AHIDALSService 1
    >!AUpstreamUserClient 3.6.8
    >!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.2.2
    @AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics 6.2.2
    >pmtelemetry 1
    >LuaHardwareAccess 1.0.16
    |IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
    |IO!BSerialManager 8.0.3d9
    @Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0
    >!AHV 1
    >!ADiskImages2 1
    >!A!IKBLGraphics 16.0.1
    >!AThunderboltIP 4.0.3
    >!AGFXHDA 100.1.431
    >!ABacklight 180.3
    >!AMCCSControl 1.14
    >BridgeAudioCommunication 100.2
    >!AAVEBridge 6.1
    >!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
    >!ABridgeAudio!C 100.2
    >!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 16.0.1
    >!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
    @filesystems.apfs 1677.81.1
    >BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore 1
    >BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore 1
    >BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore 1
    >BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore 1
    @filesystems.tmpfs 1
    @filesystems.hfs.kext 556.60.1
    @BootCache 40
    @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
    @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
    >!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac 1
    @private.KextAudit 1.0
    >!ASmartBatteryManager 161.0.0
    >!AACPIButtons 6.1
    >!ASMBIOS 2.1
    >!AACPIEC 6.1
    >!AAPIC 1.7
    @!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
    @nke.applicationfirewall 310
    |IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
    |EndpointSecurity 1
    @kext.triggers 1.0
    >!AHIDKeyboard 223
    >!AActuatorDriver 4400.28
    >!AMultitouchDriver 4400.28
    >!AInputDeviceSupport 4400.35
    >!AHS!BDriver 4030.5
    >IO!BHIDDriver 8.0.3d9
    >!AGraphicsControl 6.2.2
    |IO!BHost!CUARTTransport 8.0.3d9
    |IO!BHost!CTransport 8.0.3d9
    |IOAVB!F 930.1
    @plugin.IOgPTPPlugin 900.11
    |IOEthernetAVB!C 1.1.0
    >!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
    >!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
    >!AOnboardSerial 1.0
    >X86PlatformPlugin 1.0.0
    >!ABacklightExpert 1.1.0
    @!AGPUWrangler 6.2.2
    >!ASMBus!C 1.0.18d1
    >!UAudio 401.4
    |IONDRVSupport 585
    >IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
    |IOAudio!F 300.6.1
    @vecLib.kext 1.2.0
    |IOAccelerator!F2 439.52
    @!AGraphicsDeviceControl 6.2.2
    |IOGraphics!F 585
    |IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F 1.0.0
    >usb.cdc.ncm 5.0.0
    >usb.cdc 5.0.0
    >usb.networking 5.0.0
    >usb.!UHostCompositeDevice 1.2
    >usb.!UHub 1.2
    >usb.!UVHCIBCE 1.2
    >usb.!UVHCICommonBCE 1.0
    >usb.!UVHCI 1.2
    >usb.!UVHCICommon 1.0
    >!AEffaceableNOR 1.0
    |IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
    |IOBufferCopyEngine!F 1
    |IONVMe!F 2.1.0
    >!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
    >!AThunderboltDPInAdapter 8.1.4
    >!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F 8.1.4
    >!AHPM 3.4.4
    >!A!ILpssI2C!C 3.0.60
    >!A!ILpssDmac 3.0.60
    >!AThunderboltNHI 7.2.8
    |IOThunderbolt!F 9.3.2
    >!ABSDKextStarter 3
    |IOSurface 289.3
    @filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
    >!ABCMWLANCoreMac 1.0.0
    |IOSerial!F 11
    |IO80211!FV2 1200.12.2b1
    |IOSkywalk!F 1
    >mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b8
    >IOImageLoader 1.0.0
    >corecapture 1.0.4
    |IOUSB!F 900.4.2
    >!A!ILpssI2C 3.0.60
    >usb.!UXHCIPCI 1.2
    >usb.!UXHCI 1.2
    >!AEFINVRAM 2.1
    >!AEFIRuntime 2.1
    >!ASMCRTC 1.0
    |IOSMBus!F 1.1
    |IOHID!F 2.0.0
    $!AImage4 3.0.0
    |IOTimeSync!F 900.11
    |IONetworking!F 3.4
    >DiskImages 493.0.0
    |IO!B!F 8.0.3d9
    |IOReport!F 47
    |IO!BPacketLogger 8.0.3d9
    $quarantine 4
    $sandbox 300.0
    @kext.!AMatch 1.0.0d1
    |CoreAnalytics!F 1
    >!ASSE 1.0
    >!AKeyStore 2
    >!UTDM 511.60.2
    |IOUSBMass!SDriver 184.40.6
    |IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 436.40.6
    |IO!S!F 2.1
    |IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F 436.40.6
    >!AMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5
    @kext.CoreTrust 1
    >!AFDEKeyStore 28.30
    >!AEffaceable!S 1.0
    >!ACredentialManager 1.0
    >KernelRelayHost 1
    |IOUSBHost!F 1.2
    >!UHostMergeProperties 1.2
    >usb.!UCommon 1.0
    >!ABusPower!C 1.0
    >!ASEPManager 1.0.1
    >IOSlaveProcessor 1
    >!AACPIPlatform 6.1
    >!ASMC 3.1.9
    |IOPCI!F 2.9
    |IOACPI!F 1.4
    >watchdog 1
    @kec.pthread 1
    @kec.corecrypto 11.1
    @kec.Libm 1
    panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80181e2960): "Spinlock acquisition timed out: lock=0xffffff86dd946290, lock owner thread=0xffffff86d4035120, current_thread: 0xffffff86d42e6e30, lock owner active on CPU 0x6, current owner: 0xffffff86d4035120, time: 91030942220121"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-7195.81.3/osfmk/i386/locks_i386.c:505
    Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
    0xffffffa085c4dab0 : 0xffffff80180bab4d
    0xffffffa085c4db00 : 0xffffff80181fd7e3
    0xffffffa085c4db40 : 0xffffff80181ede1a
    0xffffffa085c4db90 : 0xffffff801805fa2f
    0xffffffa085c4dbb0 : 0xffffff80180ba3ed
    0xffffffa085c4dcd0 : 0xffffff80180ba6d8
    0xffffffa085c4dd40 : 0xffffff80188bef9a
    0xffffffa085c4ddb0 : 0xffffff80181e2960
    0xffffffa085c4ddf0 : 0xffffff80180db0fa
    0xffffffa085c4de30 : 0xffffff80180db01c
    0xffffffa085c4de60 : 0xffffff8018108d7b
    0xffffffa085c4df20 : 0xffffff80181d98b3
    0xffffffa085c4df60 : 0xffffff80181f6eaa
    0xffffffa085c4df80 : 0xffffff80181ed5bb
    0xffffffa085c4dfd0 : 0xffffff801805fbdd
    0xffffffb0c94e3db0 : 0xffffff80181123d1
    0xffffffb0c94e3e10 : 0xffffff80186795e9
    0xffffffb0c94e3f00 : 0xffffff8018678716
    0xffffffb0c94e3f40 : 0xffffff80187698cb
    0xffffffb0c94e3fa0 : 0xffffff80180601f6
    
    Process name corresponding to current thread: Messenger Helper (Rendere
```

Comment: Hey please check this answer that says it might be an hardware issue:
https://superuser.com/a/545543/1134445